# How to get datasource attributes via CAS by different entry key

Tags: java, authentication, cas

I asked that question before but no answer. I think my question wasn't clear so I'll try again:

I am using CAS to authenticate against ldap:

I am also take attributes from DB:

```
<property>
  <list>
    <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver"/>
    <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.CredentialsToLDAPAttributePrincipalResolver">
      <property name="credentialsToPrincipalResolver">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver"/>
      </property>
      <property name="filter" value="(uid=%u)"/>
      <property name="principalAttributeName" value="uid"/>
      <property name="searchBase" value="ou=Users,dc=openiam,dc=com"/>
      <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSource"/>
      <property name="attributeRepository" ref="attributeRepository"/>
    </bean>
  </list>
</property>
```

Now the entry key to select the attributes from the database is by the username which was retrieved from LDAP:

```
<bean class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.jdbc.SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao">
            <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource1"/>
            <constructor-arg index="1" value="SELECT * FROM USER_DATA WHERE {0}"/>
            <property name="queryAttributeMapping">
              <map>
                <entry key="username" value="LOGINNAME"/>
                   //here I would like to use diffrenty entry key than username. how?

              </map>
            </property>
            <property name="resultAttributeMapping">
              <map>
                <entry key="ROLE_NAME" value="ROLE_NAME"/>
                <entry key="PERMISSIONS" value="PERMISSIONS"/>
                <entry key="APP_NAME" value="APP_NAME"/>
              </map>
            </property>
          </bean>


<entry key="username" value="uid"/>
```

In my case I would like to select the attributes from the Database via different entry key (which was retrieved from the LDAP).

For example:

let's say I have this record in ldap:

username: john

email: john@john.com

Now after authentication I want to select from the Database the attributes this way: 
select * from USERS_ATTRS where email={0}

- {0} is the email attribute which was retrieved from LDAP.

thanks.